# Using IBM FileNet Web services in C# Application

Tags: c#, filenet-p8

Our organization uses IBM FileNet as document management system. FileNet P8 comes with a web services API which can be used in .net

Has anyone of you guys tried this? If yes could you please direct me to any resources to kick start?

Thanks a ton in advance.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v4r5m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/content_engine_api/guide/gs_procedures.htm

Comment: I've never used it myself.. But I found samples that MIGHT be useful here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=3278&uid=swg27010422


Do a find on the page for .NET

Comment: David, Thank you very much for posting this link. Thanks again and have a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right place for documentation related to the P8 .Net API.  The only other "kick-start" link I can think of is http://www.ecmplace.com/.

I know how to create a session using the Java API for the CE, but I'm sorry to say that I haven't done it with the .Net API.  However, I'm fairly certain that you'll find helpful examples on the ECM Place forum.

HTH!

Tom Purl

Answer (score 7):

The FileNet API comes in 5 flavors:

- Java - jar reference, configure to use either http or iiop transport
- .NET - .NET dll reference, configure for http transport
- CEWS - Content Engine Web Services. Use [only if you can't use the Java or .NET API](http://www.google.com/search?q="use+either+the+Content+Engine+Java+API+or+the+Content+Engine+.NET+API")
- CMIS - web service conforming to the CMIS spec
- COM - semi-legacy, not discussed in the docs, but it does exist

Although the .NET API uses web services in the background, your .NET project reference is to FileNet.Api.dll, rather than directly to the WSDL. So if you're a .NET shop, you want the .NET API, not the "Web Services API" (2012-02-03 edit: unless you opt for CMIS)

The best place to get started is the "Bulk Loader Sample Code" here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=3278&uid=swg27010422